# How to embed Google Maps "Send to your phone" button

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to embed Google Maps "Send to your phone" button in a custom site. No results searching in Google documentation and search engine. Is it possible?

"Send to your phone" button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps APIs do not provide this functionality out-of-the-box, but you can use (1) [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) (2) Google Maps Intents for Android or (3) Google Maps URL Schemes for IOS to implement this.

Check out Google's documentation on how to launch Google Maps on [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intents) and [IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme).

Hope this helps.